# When click a button add value to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".buttons").click(function(){
         var cntrl = $(this).html(); 
         $("#txt-area").text(cntrl+",");

         //alert (cntrl);
     });
});

</script>
```

When I click to my character on my html page character's value sets to textarea, but when I click to another character previous char disappears. I know about something about arrays in JS but how can I handle this.

How can I add values to textarea properly without disappearing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val) {
            return val + cntrl + ","
        });

        //alert (cntrl);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cPYCV/)

or

```
$("#txt-area").text($("#txt-area").val() + cntrl+",");
$("#txt-area").append(cntrl + ",");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YD6PL/) - I prefer using val() because I consider it as a input element

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot but I want to learn about val(function (_, val)? Could you explain this part?

Comment: @hakiko [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) takes a function as a parameter whose return value will be set as the value of the current element. The function will get 2 parameters the index of current element and current value of the element. So we just add the value of the button to the current value and return it so that the concatenated value is set as the new value.

Comment: @hakiko that is just a valid parameter name, it can easily be `index`, `i` etc

Answer (score 1):

Arun's answer above works, but it will add a comma to the end. If you want to avoid that, place the comma before the new value, and then have the code check to see if this is the first time something is being added, and not place a comma that time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oldvalue;
    var newvalue;
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        oldvalue = $("#txt-area").val();  //GET THE VALUE OF TEXTBOX WHEN USER CLICKS
        if (oldvalue) {newvalue = ', '+$(this).html();} // IF THE TEXTBOX ISN'T BLANK, PLACE A COMMA BEFORE THE NEW VALUE
        else {newvalue = $(this).html();} //IF THE TEXTBOX IS BLANK, DON'T ADD A COMMA
        $("#txt-area").val(oldvalue + newvalue); //PLACE THE ORIGINAL AND NEW VALUES INTO THE TEXTBOX.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $(".buttons").click(function(){ 
          var cntrl = $(this).html();
          var xTxtArea = $("#txt-area");
          xTxtArea.text(xTxtArea.text() + cntrl + ","); 
     }); 
});
```